# Select statement to select only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My item has several images store in a table.

I want to retrieve only the first image.

How can I do that please?

This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Item.ItemID, Item.Name, Item.Description, Item.Quantity, 
   Item.Condition, Category.Name AS Expr1, Auction.EndDate, Auction.CurrencyValuePost, 
   Image.Image
FROM
   Item 
INNER JOIN
   Category ON Item.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID 
INNER JOIN
   Image ON Item.ItemID = Image.ItemID 
INNER JOIN
   Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID
WHERE        
   (Auction.Status = 'Valid')
```

Comment: You could use Top 1 instead

Comment: IF I USED TOP 1 IT WILL GIVE ONLY THE FIRST RECORD ME I WANT EVERY ITEM IN THE TABLE BUT WITH ONLY THE FIRST IMAGES IN THE TABLE IMAGE

Comment: As first image you mean Image.Image ? If I understand correctly you want to select table with only one column - images?

Comment: yes i want to select each item with their first image in the table image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * From
(
SELECT
    Item.ItemID,
    Item.Name,
    Item.Description, 
    Item.Quantity,  
    Item.Condition,
    Category.Name AS Expr1,
    Auction.EndDate, 
    Auction.CurrencyValuePost, 
    Image.Image,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  Item.ItemID ORDER BY  Item.ItemID ASC) AS RN
FROM Item 
    INNER JOIN Category ON Item.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID 
    INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID
    LEFT JOIN Image ON Item.ItemID = Image.ItemID 
WHERE Auction.Status = 'Valid'
) AS T
Where RN=1
```

Comment: I have added here. please check now

Comment: you can see tick mark top left in my answer. please tick that.and upvote for other reference

Comment: the code is working in my query but it is telling me that  The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported. and when i paste in in my sql statement to retrieve data no data appear

Comment: in the query builder the code is work perfectly but before it run it say that the over sql construct or statement is not supported,but when used it as 
dim sql as string ="" and pass it to my command for execute nothing appear and nothing bind

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Item.ItemID,
    Item.Name,
    Item.Description, 
    Item.Quantity,  
    Item.Condition,
    Category.Name AS Expr1,
    Auction.EndDate, 
    Auction.CurrencyValuePost, 
    Image.Image
FROM Item 
    INNER JOIN Category ON Item.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID 
    INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID
    LEFT JOIN Image ON Item.ItemID = Image.ItemID 
WHERE        (Auction.Status = 'Valid')
```

Comment: @user1784696 maybe you should better post tables structure.